# PHP::Serialization gives an error when trying to serialize HTTP::Response

Tags: perl, serialization

[PHP::Serialization](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PHP%3a%3aSerialization) gives an error when trying to serialize [HTTP::Response](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTTP%3a%3aResponse).

Example follows. Any hints?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use LWP ; 
use PHP::Serialization qw(serialize unserialize); 


my $url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/' ; 
my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new() ;
my $page = $ua->get($url) ; 

print "HTML page is ". length($page)." bytes long.\n" ; 
print $page ; print "\n" ; 

my $buffer ; 
eval { $buffer = serialize($page); } ; die $@ if $@ ;    


open FH, '>stored.dat' or die "Cannot create store file $!" ; 
binmode FH ; 
print FH $buffer ; 
close FH ;
```

The execution gives:

```
HTML page is 30 bytes long.
HTTP::Response=HASH(0x901f110)
Not a HASH reference at /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1/PHP/Serialization.pm line 454.
```

Going further with my serialization / de-serialization experiments I tried the FreezeThaw
package. As you can see in the following snippet it works but I got another problem.
The rebuilt (de-serialized) object has no type, hence I cannot use its methods. I cannot
"bless" it either because it is a "non-reference".

How should I approach this problem ?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use HTML::Parser ; 
use HTML::Form ; 
use HTTP::Response ; 
use LWP ; 

use FreezeThaw qw(freeze thaw cmpStr safeFreeze cmpStrHard);

my $url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/' ; 
my $ua  = LWP::UserAgent->new() ;
my $page = $ua->get($url) ; 

print "HTML page is ". length($page)." bytes long.\n" ; 
print $page ; print "\n" ; 
print $page->status_line(), "\n" ; 

my $buffer ; 
eval { $buffer = freeze($page); } ; die $@ if $@ ;    

print "Serdes buffer is ". length($buffer)." bytes long.\n" ; 

open FH, '>stored.dat' or die "Cannot create store file $!" ; 
binmode FH ; 
print FH $buffer ; 
close FH ; 

my $otherb ; 
open FH, '<stored.dat' or die "Cannot open store file $!" ; 
binmode FH ; 
$otherb = do { local($/); <FH> } ; 
close FH ; 

print "Serdes buffer is ". length($otherb)." bytes long.\n" ; 

my $proto = HTTP::Response->new() ; 
my $recpg ; 

eval { $recpg = thaw ($otherb); } ; die $@ if $@ ; 

print $recpg ; 
#bless $recpg, ref($proto)||$proto ; 
bless $recpg, "HTTP::Response" ; 
print $recpg ; 

#print $recpg->status_line(), "\n" ;
```

The execution gives:

```
% ./serdesLab2.pl 
HTML page is 30 bytes long.
HTTP::Response=HASH(0x970ea10)
200 OK
Serdes buffer is 214347 bytes long.
Serdes buffer is 214347 bytes long.
Can't bless non-reference value at ./serdesLab2.pl line 45.
1% 
%
```

Thanks for any possible solutions.

Comment: Incidentally, the comments on the documentation for [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) read like the front page of [thedailywtf](http://thedailywtf.com).

Answer (score 1):

When you do

```
my $page = $ua->get($url);
```

You're getting an `HTTP::Response` object. You need to call the `$response->content` method to get the content of the response.

```
my $response = $ua->get($url);
die "didn't get a page: ".$response->status_line."\n" unless $response->is_success;
my $page = $response->content;
```

The error message is complaining that PHP::Serialize doesn't know how to serialize something that isn't a plain perl HASH/ARRAY ref (perhaps a CODE ref in this instance).

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP::Response` and/or `HTTP::Request` objects (I can't remember which) have a member `_uri` which is usually a [URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/URI). That object is a blessed scalar ref.

Looking around the line where the error is reported from, it seems like `PHP::Serialization` considers all objects to be hash based. Therefore, it chokes when it comes across an object which is a blessed scalar ref.

Note:

> `=head1 TODO`
>
> Support diffrent object types

I do not know the serialization format to be able to suggest a patch, but the fix would look like:

```
elsif ( $type eq 'obj' ) {
    my $class = ref($val);
    $class =~ /(\w+)$/;
    my $subclass = $1;

    my $reftype = reftype $val;
    if ($reftype eq 'HASH') {
        # blessed hash serialization
    }
    elsif ($reftype eq 'ARRAY') {
        # blessed array serialization
    }
    elsif ($reftype eq 'SCALAR') {
        # blesssed scalar serialization
    }
    elsif ($reftype eq 'CODE') {
        # blessed coderef serialization
    }
    elsif ($reftype eq 'GLOB') {
        # blessed globref serialization
    }
    else {
        # etc etc
    }
```

where `reftype` comes from [Scalar::Util](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Scalar::Util). In fact, it would be useful to fill in those branches, or turn this into a dispatch table, if only to croak when an unsupported type is encountered.